# Knowledge owl security issue, contents ecurity policy example

Tags: security, dom, xss

I enabled content security policies in knowledgeowl portal, however I still can see xss injection is possible vial url.  Any script can be passed as queryParam configUrl and can be executed. Xss injection is possible. How to fix this. Is there any option to restart after changing settings.

I tried enabling content security policy checkbox provided in settings but it is not working